# Java programming with one base code and multiple versions

Tags: java, design-patterns, web-applications

Basically, I have a 'base' code that is the main body of the program and would like to be able to add separate libraries/modules/over classes based on individual requirements for each 'customer'. When i set up the program, i'll select the version (base, customer1,customer2). This is a webbed based service running on a tomcat7 apache server, Java1.8.

Is there something like this possible?

Edit: some customizations are as small as a new field, or a new method, or a new class.

Comment: *When i set up the program, i'll select the version*. Do you mean to make this selection at runtime or at deployment time?

Comment: @CKing Deployment would be best, I would like make it as simple as just selecting a version. maybe like an installer?

Answer (score 0):

correct me if i'm wrong but it sounds like you want some core code to your system, which you can then add functionality to in order to customise it for particular customers.

The customisation can be achieved by writing your code using an OSGI framework such as apache felix or equinox(built into eclipse). These frameworks are ostensibly plugin frameworks that allow you to add and remove modules on the fly, but it also allows you to write code as a seperate bundles that can be combined to your specification. [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077837/application-development/java-se-hello-osgi-part-1-bundles-for-beginners.html) is a good tutorial on using equinox.

Regarding automating the task of per customer customisations, it could be worth your while to look into something like [Chef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_(software)) which is used for the automatic configuration of server software like apache or mysql, it will allow you to write a "recipe" for each customers individual customisations. All you would have to do once the various OSGI plugins have been written is to write a script to put them together and run it, after which you could send the customised software to the customer.

Comment: I dont have to customize it on a webservice, Currently i have the core code, and a duplicate code with customizations for this customer. So when i make changes to the core code, i'll have have to make changes to every duplicate as well. which is fine when i have a couple, but not when i have 50+ for example. I'm looking to get it done in a way where i can just have the core code, and the customizations as like 'plugins' or overriding classes.

Comment: I have changed my post to better reflect your needs, I hope this helps.

Comment: Chef seems like something im looking for but it's using Ruby. My code is in Java, will i beable to use it to 'compile' my bunch of code together?

Comment: That shouldnt be a problem.